# click function gets only the last id from the table

Tags: javascript, php, post, event-listener

İm trying to update a data on my database using java script and php and my js code looks like this

```
var randevuiptal = document.getElementsByClassName("las la-trash-alt");
                        for (var i = 0; i < randevuiptal.length; i++) {
                        randevuiptal[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                        //alert(randevubilgi.saat_id);
                        localStorage.setItem("saat_id", randevubilgi.saat_id);             
                        });               
                    
                        var formData = new FormData();

                        formData.append("saat_id", localStorage.getItem("saat_id"));

                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("POST", "../../backend/randevu-iptal.php", true);
                        xhr.send(formData);

                        xhr.onload = function () {
                        console.log(this.response);
                        
                        };
                    }
```

and this is my php file

```
<?php 

require("sistem/baglan.php");

if($_POST){

$saatid= $_POST["saat_id"];
$saatdurum = "bos";

$guncelle = $db -> prepare("UPDATE saat SET saat_durum=? WHERE saat_id=?");
$guncelle -> execute(array($saatdurum,$saatid));

}
?>
```

so when i click the "las la-trash-alt" button i need it to take the id of the clicked row and then post it to php file to update but right now when i click the button it just takes all the id's (i tried it with the alert it shows all the ids to the end from the one which is clicked) and updates the datas of the last id

Comment: Hi, put `var formData = new FormData()...` all code inside click handler.

Answer (score 0):

ON PHP page fetch only AutoIncrement column eg SR, make it descending and limit 1
example query :
SELECT * FROM `TableName` ORDER BY `sr` DESC LIMIT 1